# How can I include a group's average in every row of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select columns from a table, and also include the average of their groups as its own column.

For example, I have a table of food information for a restaurant. The columns are: Meal (Breakfast, Lunch, or Dinner), Item (various food options), and Cost (price of each item).
I want the output to show each Item, the Meal group it falls under, and the average cost of Items within that Meal.

So, if Item A costs 4, and Item B costs 2, and they are both Breakfast items, I want the table output to show:

A  | Breakfast | 3

B | Breakfast |  3

I tried this

`SELECT Item, Meal, AVG(Cost) FROM Table GROUP BY Meal`

But this is not what I'm looking for. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use `AVG` as a window function:

```
SELECT Item, Meal, AVG(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY Meal) AvgCost
FROM yourTable;
```